# How do I find Lili?

Tags: mods, kerbal-space-program

In the [GPP mod](https://forum.kerbalspaceprogram.com/index.php?/topic/152136-ksp-145-galileos-planet-pack-v1631-03-aug-2018/&tab=comments#comment-2853053) for Kerbal, they decided to remove Lili from the map:

> Deleted Lili's orbit line from tracking station/map view.

Ok... so, how am I suppose to find Lili? Just by flying around will probably not be a good idea.

UPDATE: Is that piece of rock Lili???
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That small piece of rock IS Lili. It's extremely hard to find but was placed in a more or less obvious place to find if you are investigating Tellumo.

Here are a couple of screenshots of Lili:
[image]
[image]

It's located in the dark part of Tellumo ring.
It's only possible to see when it's passing in front of the sun.
Landing on it seems to be nearly impossible because the ground will kick you back to orbit.
Orbiting it is easier:

- Align with Tellumo's rings;
- Put your periapsis in the dark ring;
- At some point you will encounter Lili.
- When it happens, just retrograde until you have an orbit around it.

If I have to guess, the only way to land and stay there is using the Klaw.

UPDATE: It's not possible to use the Klaw in Lili. The best way to land and stay there is to NOT use landing gear or you will bounce back into atmosphere but let your ship lay down into the big crater. Retract antenna and solar panels and let the ship just fall into the ground.

Comment: Landing on the poles might be possible, since the rotational speed is lower there.

Comment: It is not. I tried landing there at 0,1 m/s and got kicked very high. Managed to land on the engine without the kick but when I reload the game, Lili kick me high too.

Comment: Probably need the klaw.

Comment: You may try KAS harpoons instead, like [that](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hITCCkJg8WA).